# Can AVS(Alexa voice service) be used on website with wake word?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I'm trying to add AVS and Skill on my web site, and I can see it is possible to add a button to activate Alexa like echosim.io, but not sure how to initiate with wake word by voice.
Is it possible and any chance of some example of javascript?

Comment: I want to say no, or at least, this would probably be very difficult. First you have to make sure that the browser lets you access the microphone and keep the microphone recording. Then you need to do audio processing in JavaScript (I don't know of any libraries) to detect the wakeword, and then, once detected, stream the audio to Alexa like echosim does.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I found some library, vad.js(https://github.com/kdavis-mozilla/vad.js/tree/master), which would work for wake word. But not go thru yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Porcupine](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine) and then route the audio to AVS. It has NPM packages for Angular, React, and Vue.